# Buscar e exibir em uma listview um unico tipo de informação do BD

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-studio, postgresql

Estou tendo problemas para buscar um único tipo de informação do BD, eu já criei uma lista onde trago todas as informações nele presente, porem quero puxar somente uma, por exemplo buscar somente os nomes dos clientes e exibir todos em um listView, será que alguem poderia me ajudar ?

```
public class Usuario extends _default {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String data;
    private String rg;
    private String cpf;
    private String doenca;
    private String alergia;
    private String profissao;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getDoenca() {
        return doenca;
    }

    public void setDoenca(String doenca) {
        this.doenca = doenca;
    }

    public String getAlergia() {
        return alergia;
    }

    public void setAlergia(String alergia) {
        this.alergia = alergia;
    }

    public String getProfissao() {
        return profissao;
    }

    public void setProfissao(String profissao) {
        this.profissao = profissao;
    }

    public Usuario(){
        super();
        this.id = -1;
        this.nome = "";
        this.data = "";
        this.rg = "";
        this.cpf = "";
        this.doenca = "";
        this.alergia = "";
        this.profissao = "";
    }

    public ArrayList<Usuario> getLista(){
        BD bd = new BD();
        ArrayList<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = bd.select("SELECT * FROM usuario");
            if(resultSet != null ){
                while (resultSet.next()){
                    Usuario obj = new Usuario();
                    obj.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    obj.setNome(resultSet.getString("nome"));
                    obj.setData(resultSet.getString("data"));
                    obj.setRg(resultSet.getString("rg"));
                    obj.setCpf(resultSet.getString("cpf"));
                    obj.setDoenca(resultSet.getString("doenca"));
                    obj.setAlergia(resultSet.getString("alergia"));
                    obj.setProfissao(resultSet.getString("profissao"));
                    lista.add(obj);
                    obj = null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
            this._status = false;

        }
        return lista;
    }

    public void confirmar(){
        String comando = "";
        if(this.getId() == -1){
           comando = String.format("INSERT INTO usuario (nome, data, rg, cpf, doenca, alergia, profissao) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s' );",
                    this.getNome(), this.getData(), this.getRg(), this.getCpf(), this.getDoenca(), this.getAlergia(), this.getProfissao());
          /* try {
               comando = String.format("SELECT * FROM usuario");
           }catch(Exception e)
            {
              _messagem = "Não entrou no BD";
            }*/

        }
        else
        {
            comando = String.format("UPDATE usuario SET nome ='%s', date = '%s', rg = '%s', cpf = '%s', doenca = '%s', alergia = '%s', profissao = '%s' WHERE id = %d;",
                    this.getNome(), this.getData(), this.getRg(), this.getCpf(), this.getDoenca(), this.getAlergia(), this.getProfissao(), this.getId());
        }
        BD bd = new BD();
       bd.execute(comando);
       this._messagem = bd._messagem;
        this._status = bd._status ;
    }

    public void apagar(){
        String  comando =  String.format("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id = %d ", this.getId());

        BD bd = new BD();
        bd.execute(comando);
        this._messagem = bd._messagem;
        this._status = bd._status ;


    }

}



public class UsuarioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Usuario> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Usuario> lista;

public UsuarioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Usuario> lista)
    {
        super(context,0,lista);
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final Usuario itemPosicao = this.lista.get(position);
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.item_lista,null);
        final View layout = convertView;

        TextView textViewNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
        textViewNome.setText(itemPosicao.getNome());

        TextView textViewData = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
        textViewData.setText(itemPosicao.getData());

        TextView textViewRg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRg);
        textViewRg.setText(itemPosicao.getRg());

        TextView textViewCpf = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCpf);
        textViewCpf.setText(itemPosicao.getCpf());

        TextView textViewDoenca = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDoenca);
        textViewDoenca.setText(itemPosicao.getDoenca());

        TextView textViewAlergia = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAlergia);
        textViewAlergia.setText(itemPosicao.getAlergia());

        TextView textViewProfissao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfissao);
        textViewProfissao.setText(itemPosicao.getProfissao());

       /* Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEditar);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Novo.class);
            intent.putExtra("nome", itemPosicao.getNome());
            intent.putExtra("data", itemPosicao.getData());
            intent.putExtra("rg", itemPosicao.getRg());
            intent.putExtra("cpf", itemPosicao.getCpf());
            intent.putExtra("doenca", itemPosicao.getDoenca());
            intent.putExtra("alergia", itemPosicao.getAlergia());
            intent.putExtra("profissao", itemPosicao.getProfissao());
            context.startActivity(intent);
           }
        });
    Button buttonDeletar = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonApagar);
        buttonDeletar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemPosicao.apagar();
                if (itemPosicao._status)
                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(context, itemPosicao.get_messagem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });*/

        return convertView;

    }

}


public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listViewUsuario;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

        this.listViewUsuario = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewUsuario);
        this.listViewUsuario.setAdapter(new UsuarioAdapter(this, new Usuario().getLista()));
    }
    public void voltar(View view){
        finish();
    }


}


public class Novo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Usuario usuario;
    private EditText editTextNome;
    private EditText editTextData;
    private EditText editTextRg;
    private EditText editTextCpf;
    private EditText editTextDoenca;
    private EditText editTextAlergia;
    private EditText editTextProfissao;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo);

        this.usuario = new Usuario();
        this.editTextNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
        this.editTextData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
        this.editTextRg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRg);
        this.editTextCpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCpf);
        this.editTextDoenca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDoenca);
        this.editTextAlergia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAlergia);
        this.editTextProfissao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProfissao);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
            if(intent != null){
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if(bundle != null){
                    this.usuario.setId(bundle.getInt("id"));
                    this.editTextNome.setText(bundle.getString("nome"));
                    this.editTextData.setText(bundle.getInt("data"));
                    this.editTextRg.setText(bundle.getString("rg"));
                    this.editTextCpf.setText(bundle.getString("cpf"));
                    this.editTextDoenca.setText(bundle.getString("doenca"));
                    this.editTextAlergia.setText(bundle.getString("alergia"));
                    this.editTextProfissao.setText(bundle.getString("profissao"));

                }
            }
    }

    public void confirmar (View view){
        this.usuario.setNome(this.editTextNome.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setData(this.editTextData.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setRg(this.editTextRg.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setCpf(this.editTextCpf.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setDoenca(this.editTextDoenca.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setAlergia(this.editTextAlergia.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setProfissao(this.editTextProfissao.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.confirmar();

        Toast.makeText(this,this.usuario.get_messagem(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(usuario._status)
            finish();
    }

    public void cancelar (View view)
    {

        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o erro ? Explique melhor o problema...

Comment: O problema é q eu não sei pegar as informaçoes q estão na base de dados e passar somente um parâmetro para a listview, por que quando tento fazer isso da conflito com o UsuarioAdapter q pega todas as informações, gostaria de saber um jeito de pegar essas informações com um parâmetro, por exemplo só os nomes dos usuarios, e jogar em uma listview em outra activity...

Comment: Eu estou utilizando o Android Studio, com a linguagem Java e o meu banco é  PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Tenho um exemplo velho dos meus trabalhos com android na faculdade. Aqui eu crio num novo ArrayAdapter< String> pra pegar apenas um valor (da forma que você quer).
Não pode esquecer do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalhes);

    //pegando os valores passados pela activity anterior
    Double investimento = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("investimento", 0);
    Integer anos = getIntent().getIntExtra("anos", 0);
    Double rentabilidade = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("rentabilidade", 0);

    //iniciando a listview, adapter e etc
    ArrayList<String> dados = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, dados);
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstAnos);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    //calculando os paranaues
    double temp = investimento;
    double total =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < anos; i++) {
        temp = investimento * (rentabilidade/100) * i;
        total = temp+investimento;
        dados.add(i + "º ano - $" + total);
    }

    //atualiza o campo do total
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotal)).setText("" + total);

    //notificando modificação pra atualizar a listview
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu ia falar pra você criar um array adapter pra cada filtragem que vc quer, então se vc quer só os nome dos users chama um array adapter só com o "this.usuario.setNome".

Answer (score -2):

Você provavelmente está armazenando cada usuário dentro de um array, confere? Cria um método na classe que retorne o nome, em seguida varre o array usando o método. O mais difícil você já fez, cara.